# AmazonPay to redirect on the same page once the customer logded in, using php SDK

Tags: javascript, php, sdk, amazon-pay

**Edited**

I am trying to implement the amazonPay to my website on checkout. Following their documents, I started writing the code. As of now for testing purpose, I redirect the user to another page once they loggedin with their amazon account and on that page the user are able to see the address and payment methods widgets. Now I want the flow like this: Once user clicks on 'Pay with Amazon' button on 'checkout.php', amazon login window will be pop-up and when the user successfully logged in and if access token is generated, they should redirect to the same page(checkout.php) and they should see the address and payment method widgets on that page only after they successfully logged in. I want to do this as my order details are on that page, so will be easy to get the order reference id from that page.

In **index.php**

```
<div id="AmazonPayButton"></div>
<!-- <div id="addressBookWidgetDiv"></div> -->
<!-- <div id="walletWidgetDiv"></div> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var authRequest;
    OffAmazonPayments.Button("AmazonPayButton", "<?php echo $amazonpay_config['merchant_id']; ?>", {
        type:  "PwA",
        color: "Gold",
        size:  "small",

        authorization: function() {
            loginOptions = { 
                scope: "profile payments:widget", 
                popup: "true"
            };
            authRequest = amazon.Login.authorize(loginOptions, "checkout.php");
        },
        onError: function(error) {
          // your error handling code
        }
    });
</script
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: `client_id` undefined?

Comment: Yes that's what I am getting

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the domain the button is being rendered on is whitelisted in your [Allowed JS Origins](https://pay.amazon.com/us/developer/documentation/lpwa/201956540). It's also important to make sure that the protocol matches, http, https, etc, and to confirm that the correct client_id is being used. If you continue to have trouble, reach out to [Amazon Pay's merchant support](http://pay.amazon.com/contact), as they can assist with your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks. I would contact the support.